# “Habría” or “Hubiera”: ¿Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les "hubiera" o "habría" costado tanto recordarlo?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sintaxis, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, condicional

Dada la siguiente oración:

> Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les **hubiera** (**habría**) costado tanto recordarlo.

se ve que la primera aparición de *hubieran* está bien utilizada, pero a veces la segunda no es tan fácil de elegir en vez de *habría*.

¿Cuál es la elección más usada, o al menos la más "entendible"?

---

Given the following sentence:

> Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les **hubiera** (**habría**) costado tanto recordarlo.

we see that the first use of *hubieran* is well used, but the second one is sometimes difficult to choose instead *habría*.

Which is the most used choice, or at least the most "understandable" one?

Comment: The first verb on your sentence states the hypothetical condition, thus it's a subjunctive verb. The second is the conclusion, it doesn't have to be subjunctive.
In English you say 'if I were rich I would go...'  the first verb is the subjunctive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bears a direct correspondence to the classic confusion between subjuntive and conditional, for hypothetical situations:

> Si **pidieras** ayuda, tus cosas **marcharían** mejor.  (If you
>   asked for help, things would go better) (Present Unreal Conditional)

This is the correct form for the present case (subjuntive/conditional). It would be clearly wrong to use conditional instead of subjuntive in the first term ("si pedirías") or to use subjuntive for the second ("tus cosas fueran mejor") -  the later is not so wrong as the former, but it's still wrong.

The same sentence, in the past, takes the form:

> Si **hubieras pedido** ayuda, tus cosas **habrían marchado** mejor.
>   (If you'd asked for help, things would have gone better).

This is the correct way, but in this case, the substitution are more acceptable, specially the second one: "hubieran marchado mejor" is almost right, and both forms are used.

So, in the question example, "habría" is slighly more correct, but "hubiera" is acceptable.

More cases and examples [here](http://www.espanolsinfronteras.com/LenguaCastellana-RD01-Gramatica28-CondicionalImperfecto-Perfecto.htm).

Answer (score 12):

You will never go wrong using either of these standard forms:

- Si tu hermana me **llamara**, te lo **diría**.
- Si tu hermana me **llamase**, te lo **diría**.

That pair are completely interchangeable: no meaning changes when you switch between *–ra* and *–se* in the protasis (the “if” part).  However, there **are** other, rarer scenarios.

The *–se* forms are always imperfect subjunctives.  The *–ra* forms **usually** are, but they also have several other non-subjunctive uses you should be aware of, one of which may be operative here.  One is common, one is not uncommon, and one is comparatively rare.

---

## Conditionals using *–ra* instead of *–ía*

Although the *‑ra* forms are normally subjunctive, they actually **can** be conditional — and in some cases even the indicative past perfect.

First consider:

- **Quisiera** un gran abrazo.
- ¿Me lo **pudieras** explicar?
- **Debieras** decírselo.

Notice those are in main clauses, not subordinate ones. They are polite conditionals, not subjunctives at all.  And they are pretty common, especially the first one there with *quisiera*; the other two can sound a bit funny but if you hear them, that’s what they mean.

What’s happening is that one **can** use an *‑ra* form, especially with verbs like *haber, deber, poder*, in place of the conditional. That does not mean that the second half has become subjunctive. It is still conditional.

> [Con los verbos *querer, haber, deber, poder* y *valer* es frecuente el empleo de la forma en *–ra* sustituyendo en el verbo principal a los condicionales simple (*–ría*) y compuesto (*habría*...), así como al presente de indicativo sin cambio de significado.](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20de%20subjuntivo%20-%20formas%20-ra%20y%20-se.htm)

This happens quite often with those particular verbs.  Now, the *‑se* forms are always, always subjunctives, so they can only occur in the protasis, never in the apodosis.  But with the verbs listed above, you could actually have them in the apodosis if the protasis were in the past subjunctive.  [See here](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Condicional%20-%20alternancias.htm) for more examples of this.  These are examples from that page:

- Si en el seno de algún pueblo católico **cundiera** tan abominable vicio, se **estremecieran** de horror aun las potestades del infierno.
- Qué tonto **hubiera andado** yo, si **hubiera escogido** en albricias los despojos de la primera aventura.
- Si la carretera **estuviese** buena, **debieras** llegar en dos horas.

That doesn’t necessarily mean that those are all advisable or equally acceptable to all speakers. But they certainly do occur.

There is even an example there mixing them around a bit:

- Si **pidieras** que lo **hiciese**, yo lo **haría**.

That one sounds just fine to me, and I rather like the *–ra/–se* contrast the way it is used there. There you have both forms of imperfect subjunctive in the protasis, and the normal conditional in the apodosis.  It wouldn’t sound right to put an *–ra* form in that one’s apodosis.

---

## Indicative uses of *‑ra* forms for pluperfect

Something that also happens but far more rarely is literary uses of the *–ra* form instead of the past perfect. That does not mean that those become subjunctive.  It is a simple (“synthetic”) tense that uses just one word with a distinct inflection, not a compound (“analytic”) one using both an inflected auxiliary verb and the original’s participle to compose a two-word compound.

This one-word version comes straight out of Latin. You're most apt to come across it either in the written language of literature or else in Castilian speakers from the northwest of the Iberian Peninsula under the influence of Asturian and Galician, two languages in which it is unremarkable to still use *‑ra* forms as simple (not compound) past perfect indicatives in regular speech.

So for example, the synthetic (simple) past perfect *quedara* would there substitute for the analytic (compound) past perfect *había quedado* with no change in meaning.  It is an indicative use, but it is of a strictly literary register anywhere *other* than in Galicia and Asturias, where it is still used in ordinary speech often enough.

About all this the [previously provided link](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20de%20subjuntivo%20-%20formas%20-ra%20y%20-se.htm) observes:

> Pero ambos usos indicativos (“había cantado” o “cantó”) se quedaban ya como
> propios de la literatura, porque **en la lengua hablada**, el empleo de
> *cantara* iba confundiendo con el de *cantase* como subjuntivos
> subordinados (*Dijo que lo aguardáramos o aguardásemos*), afianzándose de
> tal modo que los valores indicativos apenas si se detectan en la segunda
> mitad del siglo XVII. El castellano tenía consolidado su sistema: *había
> cantado*, por un lado; *cantó*, por otro; y *cantara*, olvidado su origen
> indicativo, solo funcionaba ya como subjuntivo. Se diferenciaba con ello
> del gallego, que mantendría hasta hoy *cantara* con valor de
> pluscuamperfecto: *Chamou cando ti xa marcharas* (‘llamó cuando tú ya te
> habías marchado’).

I don’t know that I’ve every heard it spoken spontaneously myself. But you do come upon it from time to time if you read literature, especially but not uniquely older literature of a certain register.

Comment: You'll hear the indicative *-ra* forms in speech really only in the northwest of Spain where influence from Galician and Asturian (they both preserve the pluperfect indicative sense) help maintain it in Castilian.  Also, newspapers are notorious for using it especially after *según* and not always correctly (*foo equivale bar, según dijera alguien*)

Comment: @guifa That makes good sense. But it’s been more than 30 years since last I spent any notable time in Asturias, but back then I did spent a week up there twice. But it is so long ago that only the stereotypical and well-known “oddities” of asturianu stick with me, not its effects on castellano in bilingual speakers.

Comment: Veo que [modificaste _llamase_ por _llamara_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/12266/revisions). Seguro que lo sabes, pero ambas formas son equivalentes. Estos días ha habido preguntas al respecto de su nombre ([no lo tiene](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22079/1674)) y se recuperó otra sobre [dónde se usa cada cual](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8365/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui Sólo intercambié el orden de los dos primeros ejemplos, nada más. Me da igual que los llamemos «variantes en *‑ra/‑se*» o bien «desinencias *‑ra/‑se*». Espero que quede claro que ambos son igualísimos cuando representan el imperfecto del subjuntivo. Mi intento era destacar dos cositas más, ❶ que se usan las formas en *‑ra* también en sentido condicional en algunos casos bastante frecuentes, y ❷ que a veces (para la gente nombrada por arriba) aun pueden servir como pretérito pluscuamperfecto — como todavía ocurre en asturiano y gallego (y portugués y latín).

Comment: Caramba, al ver la edición no me fijé en que estuvieras cambiando el orden, lo vi como un cambio de la forma. Disculpa mi confusión. Y sí, queda claro tu punto. A todo esto, _Quisiera un gran abrazo_ sí me suena bien, pero tanto _¿Me lo pudieras explicar?_ como _Debieras decírselo_ me hacen arquear una ceja al leerlo, no me suenan idiomáticos :)

Answer (score 5):

El problema es el subjuntivo. Por lo general, la respuesta correcta es tal y como señala Alenanno: "habría". Y lo correcto (por lo general) es "habría" pues debemos tener en cuenta que una frase con todos los verbos en modo subjuntivo es una frase incompleta (a menos que se pueda completar tácitamente por el contexto) que deja al interlocutor esperando que termine la frase.

> Antonio: «Si yo hubiera comido»
>
> Enrique: «¿Qué? ¿Qué pasaría si tú hubieras comido? ¿Estarías más gordo? ¿no tendrías hambre?
>
> Antonio: «No, que digo que si yo hubiera comido entonces ya no me habría sentado mal ese whisky»
>
> Enrique: ¡Ah, vale! Ahora ya sí te entiendo.

Con las frases aisladas que nos trae Nicolás obtenemos lo siguiente:

> Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les habría costado tanto recordarlo. [OK tiene sentido por sí sola]
>
> Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les hubiera costado tanto recordarlo. [Incompleta, suena raro, como si la dijera mi hijo de 9 años]

No obstante, es posible que la segunda frase tenga sentido y esté correctamente dicha si se dice en un contexto que lo permita, por ejemplo ...

> Juan: «Si no les hubiera costado tanto recordarlo, habrían llegado a tiempo para ver el eclipse de Sol.»
>
> José: «Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les hubiera costado tanto recordarlo [y habrían visto el eclipse]»

En ambos casos es exactamente la misma frase, pero la primera carece de sentido (o por lo menos suena bastante rara) al tener todos los verbos en modo subjuntivo, y en cambio la segunda está bien pues existe un verbo (omitido pero que se sabe por el contexto) que no está en modo subjuntivo.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say:

> Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les habría costado tanto recordarlo.

But, although it seems weird to me, according to my Spanish grammar book, in the second one you can use: condicional simple, pretérito imperfecto, condicional compuesto (indicativo) and pluscuamperfecto.

Answer (score 4):

La opción correcta es la del condicional.

Una cosa que puede ayudar es recordar que una cláusula ordinal nunca puede estar en modo subjuntivo.<sup>1</sup> Entonces, como plantilla tenemos

> Si algo *hubiera/hubiese* acaecido <sub>(cláusula subordinada)</sub>, algo ______ acaecido <sub>(cláusula ordinal)</sub>.

Las únicas opciones son las que pertenecen al modo indicativo. Por lo tanto podemos descartar *hubiera*<sup>2</sup>. Ya que no funcionan temporalmente otras formas como *ha* o *habrá*, la única forma aceptable en el español estándar es *habría*. <sub>(o, supongo, *iba a haber* que es la forma perifrástica, pero suena fatal)</sub>

---

<sup>1. A menos que sea exhortativa, que es un caso obvio en su lugar y hoy día se usa casi exclusivamente como mandato o precedido por *que*.</sup>

<sup>2. Técnicamente *hubiera* puede estar en modo indicativo como un pluscuamperfecto simple, pero este tiempo es incompatible con nuestra oración hipotética.</sup>

Comment: Existe otra posibilidad en este caso: [Con los verbos *querer, haber, deber, poder* y *valer* **es frecuente el empleo de la forma en *–ra* sustituyendo en el verbo principal a los condicionales simple (*-ría*) y compuesto (*-habría...*),** así como al presente de indicativo sin cambio de significado.](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20de%20subjuntivo%20-%20formas%20-ra%20y%20-se.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Como hispano hablante, la siguiente opción:

> Si lo hubieran anotado, después no les habría costado tanto recordarlo.

Es sin duda la más usada y entendible.