# Difference between -iera and -iese ending of the imperfect subjunctive

Tags: etimología, definiciones, diferencias-regionales, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

There are two forms of the imperfect subjunctve in use, for example,

```
pudiera, pudieras, pudiera, pudiéramos, pudierais, pudieran
```

and

```
pudiese, pudieses, pudiese, pudiésemos, pudieseis, pudiesen
```

I believe that these have identical meaning (please correct if this assumption is wrong), but was there any difference historically in their origin and/or are one or other of the forms more or less commmon in different parts of the Spanish speaking world -- which may explain the historical origin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### **In English**

The *-se* forms descend from the Latin pluperfect subjunctive.  It is more common in some regions (like Spain), and has a higher frequency in writing than in speech.

The *-ra* forms descend from the simple (or synthetic) pluperfect indicative such that where as now you might see a sentence like *No quería café porque ya **había tomado** té*, in the past, would have seen *No quería café porque ya **tomara** té*.  The evidence of this past is seen in other modern-day Romance languages (Portuguese: *não queria café porque já **tomara** chá*, Asturian: *nun quería café porque yá **tomara** té*).

In most modern usage, there is no difference in the subjunctive, other than the *-se* forms perhaps being perceived as of a slightly higher register.  It is not uncommon to hear people in a single phrase alternate forms: *El profesor dijo que el alumno **comprase** el libro de la librería, **leyera** el capítulo 2, **hiciese** la tarea al final del capítulo, y **se la entregara** al principio de la siguiente clase*.

Using the *-ra* forms in the indicative is highly inadvisable, although journalists do tend to use it every now and then and every now and then you might see it in an academic paper or poetry, and (IIRC) the only other rationale the RAE gives for using it is if you're from Galicia/Asturias where the indicative form still enjoys use thanks to influence from Galician/Asturian, I'll check my *Gramática* later and update. That said, when you use *-ra* for the indicative, you may *not* alternate with *-se*, because it has never had any indicative value.  Hence an expression like *quisiera un café* (which is not actually subjunctive, it's *había querido un café*) may not be recast as *quisiese un café*.

---

### **En castellano**

Las desinencias *-se* heredan las formas del pretérito pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo del latín.  Es más común en algunos países (como España) que otros, y es más frecuente en la escritura que en el habla.

Las desinencias *-ra* vienen del pluscuamperfecto simple (o sintético) del indicativo.  En el pasado, frases como *No quería café porque ya había tomado té* habrían sido como *No quería café porque ya tomara té*.  La evidencia de este pasado se ve en otros idiomas neolatinos (portugués: *não queria café porque já tomara chá*, asturiano: *nun quería café porque yá tomara té*).

En la mayoría de los usos modernos, no hay diferencia alguna en el subjuntivo aparte de que tal vez se perciban las formas *-se* como de un registro algo más culto.  Es bastante común escuchar una única oración que alterna entre ambas formas: *El profesor dijo que el alumno **comprase** el libro de la librería, **leyera** el capítulo 2, **hiciese** la tarea al final del capítulo, y **se la entregara** al principio de la siguiente clase*.

Es difícil aconsejar que alguien use las formas *-ra* en el indicativo aunque es cierto que los periodistas la emplean a veces y de vez en cuando algún artículo académico o poema la usará.  Si recuerdo bien, la única razón que da la RAE a favor de su uso es si eres de Galicia o Asturias donde esta forma todavía disfruta un uso popular gracias a influencia del gallego/asturiano.  No obstante, si usas *-ra* para el indicativo, es *imposible* alternar con *-se*, porque *-se* nunca ha tenido ningún valor indicativo.  Por eso una expresión como *quisiera un café* (que no es subjuntivo) no se puede reescribir como *quisiese un café*.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. I have heard people use both forms in the same sentence also. Personally, I always use ara, but I suppose that is because I learnt Spanish in the Americas, so this fits with what you say.

Comment: [Relacionado](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12266/457).

Comment: Esta respuesta podría llevar un precioso `tl;dr` :p