# ¿Tienen o han tenido algún nombre concreto las dos formas del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo?

Tags: gramática, solicitud-de-término, subjuntivo, historia, pretérito-imperfecto

Comenta @pablodf76 en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22063/12637) a [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22062/12637) que las dos formas del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo no tienen un nombre oficial o aceptado entre los diferentes libros de texto que lo enseñan. Así, hablamos de "la forma en *-ra*" y "la forma en *-se*" o, como pone en la pregunta enlazada, el "imperfecto de subjuntivo" y el "imperfecto 2".

Hagamos esta pregunta oficial, y extendámosla además a un ámbito histórico: ¿tienen o han tenido alguna vez un nombre concreto cada una de las dos formas posibles de escribir el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo?

Comment: Buscando en la _Primera Gramática_ de la RAE me encuentro con que tiene un capítulo dedicado exclusivamente al uso correcto del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo, y lo primero que dice es que el tiempo tiene (bueno, tenía por aquel entonces) tres modos. Así, del verbo _ser_ tendríamos _fuera, sería, fuese_. De _haber_ tendríamos _hubiera, habría, hubiese_. Es decir, considera pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo lo que hoy día sería el condicional simple de indicativo. Se me ocurre alguna que otra pregunta que sacar de ahí...

Comment: @walen creo que sí que las he leído, pero yo me refería a preguntas más de corte histórico, como "por qué se consideraba al condicional actual como imperfecto de subjuntivo en el siglo XVIII" o "cuándo pasó la forma 'sería' a tener su propio tiempo verbal tras abandonar el imperfecto de subjuntivo".

Comment: @walen no lo digo, lo hago: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22067/12637.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preguntada a la RAE [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/905416814032773120) (qué gran recurso), me responden con [lo siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/905677444488802305):

> No, que sepamos. Se suelen utilizar denominaciones como «variante en “-ra”» y «variante en “-se”».

Yo tampoco he encontrado nada al respecto en ningún sitio, así que de momento parece que la respuesta se queda así.