# ¿Cuándo se dividieron las tres formas del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo en dos tiempos diferentes?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales, historia, rae

Al hilo de lo investigado para *[¿Tienen o han tenido algún nombre concreto las dos formas del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22064/12637)*, me encuentro con que en el siglo XVIII, allá cuando la RAE publicó su primera *Gramática de la lengua castellana* (1771), el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo incluía tres variantes:

- La terminación *-ra*.
- La terminación *-se*.
- La terminación *-ría* (el actual condicional de indicativo).

Véase un ejemplo:

[image: Tiempos del subjuntivo]

Se ve que para el verbo *amar*, la conjugación de dicho tiempo puede ser "amara", "amase" o "amaría". En cambio, el tiempo que hoy conocemos como "condicional de indicativo" no existía.

Una primera pregunta podría ser el motivo por el cual estas tres formas se solapaban por aquel entonces. Sin embargo, tengo más curiosidad por saber:

- ¿Cuándo se produjo la escisión de las tres formas en los dos tiempos verbales que hoy conocemos?
- ¿Qué motivos dio la RAE para crear un tiempo verbal nuevo y provocar dicha escisión?

Comment: Me resulta muy curioso que la primera edición del DLE que incluye una definición para "condicional" como "tiempo que expresa acción futura en relación con el pasado del que se parte" es muy reciente: la de 1992.

Answer (score 3):

A la primera, no te podría decir con certeza, excepto para decir que el estatus del condicional ha sido bastante polémico.  Hay los que dicen que es un tiempo indicativo (porque lo es claramente en una oración como *ayer me dijo que volvería a casa*, si decimos que ambos verbos en *me dice que volverá a casa* son indicativos), otros que prefieren verlo como subjuntivo (porque *lo haría si pudiese* habla de algo bastante hipotético e irreal), y otros que prefieren agrupar el condicional y el futuro en otro modo aparte (porque al responder a preguntas de tipo *¿dónde está(ba) María?* podemos decir *estará/estaría en casa*, sin indicar ni posterioridad ni irrealidad).

Pero a la segunda, la respuesta la tenemos en la Gramática sí misma:

> La primera terminacion *ra* se acomoda fácilmente á servir por alguna de las otras dos *ria* y *se* , pues lo mismo es decir : el *tiempo podria ser mejor* : que : el *tiempo pudiera ser mejor* ; y con igual propiedad se dice : *yo hice que viniese* , ó *yo hice que viniera* […]
>
> Para fixar el uso de estas tres terminaciones pudiera pretenderse que cada una conviene á un modo y tiempo diferente ; pero la variedad con que se usan , conformándose , o no la una con el valor de las otras , no permite que se fixen sus límites , y no se conseguiria otra cosa con intentarlo […]
>
> Quando el *pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo* tiene antes de sí, como determinante , alguno de los tres *pretéritos de indicativo* , y este *pretérito determinante* es alguno de los que que explican lo que se dice con la lengua , ó se concibe con el entendimiento , se usa del *pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo* en qualquiera de sus tres terminaciones : v. g.
>
> ```
> decia ........}   {vinieras.
> dixo .........}que{vendrias.
> habia dicho ..}   {vinieses.
>
> pensaba.......}   {viniera.
> pensó.........}que{vendria.
> había pensado.}   {viniese.
> ```
>
> Si el *pretérito de indicativo* es de algun verbo de los que explican voluntad , debe usarse del *pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo* en la primera, ó tercera terminacion , y no en la segunda : v. g.
>
> ```
> queria .......}   {yo tiniera , ó viniese.
> quiso ........}que{tú vinieras, ó vinieses.
> habia querido.}   {él viniera , ó viniese.
> ```

Sencillamente resumido, el hecho de que en muchas situaciones lo que hoy llamamos el condicional se empleaba como equivalente de las formas *-ra*, y para referir a acciones en el pasado, lo agruparon en este tiempo.  Pero nota que dice, «el uso de estas tres terminaciones pudiera pretenderse que cada una conviene á un modo y tiempo diferente».  Poco ha cambiado.  Hoy diríamos que son las formas *-ra* y *-se* equivalentes, pero sabemos que hay diferencias verdaderas entre ellas, e igual diríamos que *-ra* y el condicional son diferentes, a pesar de que tienen usos a veces idénticos en el castellano moderno.

Comment: Eres genial, guifa, muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y gran aportación.